# How to control 5 or more speakers from Matlab?

Tags: matlab, audio, speaker

I am looking for advice on how to control 5 or more speakers with Matlab.

In an earlier thread I received advice on the hardware needed to control the speakers. 
http://audio.stackexchange.com/questions/1541/easy-solution-for-controlling-5-or-more-speakers-from-a-single-computer

But I am still interested in advice on how to control these speakers. I tried posting on the audio forum.
http://audio.stackexchange.com/questions/1554/how-to-control-5-or-more-speakers-from-matlab
But 'Friend Of George' advised me to post here for better results.

I would appreciate your suggestions. Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to download a software interface to your audio hardware which enables Matlab to access multichannel audio driver, as the built-in Matlab audio only supports 2 channels.

I used this one in the past http://www.playrec.co.uk/, and it worked for me. It's not really a straight-forward "download and install" package, but the site has good documentation regarding how to make it work and use it.

If you want more options, search the web for "matlab multi channel audio"